# ASSEMBLY TASM, STRING OUTPUT PROB using procedure

Tags: assembly

ASSEMbLY MAStER PLEASE HELP.. IM HAVING TROUBLE IN OUTPUT,
assembly masters, please help. im having trouble in output.
the output should be:

eg.

DEstroit♥Me

but the output in my code is messed up>

where did i go wrong??
Please help
Thanks in advance;

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
.model small
.stack 0100h
.data
a db 0ah, 0dh,"ENTER FIRSTNAME: $"
b db 0ah, 0dh,"ENTER SECONDNAME: $" 
c db 20d, ?, 20d DUP("$")
d db 20d, ?, 20d DUP("$")
.code
main proc
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
call cls
call input
call output

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
main endp

;clear screen
cls proc
mov ax, 0600h
mov bh, 07h
mov cx, 0000h
mov dx, 184fh
int 10h
cls endp

;INPUT
input proc
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, OFFSET a
int 21h
mov ah, 0ah
mov dx, OFFSET c
int 21h
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, OFFSET b
int 21h
mov ah, 0ah
mov dx, OFFSET d
int 21h
input endp

;OUTPUT
output proc
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, OFFSET c+2
int 21h
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, 003h
int 21h
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, OFFSET d+2
int 21h
output endp

end main
```

Comment: Edit your question with a screenshot of your output, to understand what you mean by "messed up".

Comment: @Stephen C - Sorry if I use CAPletters

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez - Cant post screenshot, New to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding RET is necessary, but something else is needed too. Strings captured from keyboard with Oah are ended by char 13 (enter). To display these strings you have to change the char 13 by '$', like next image:

[image]

After we capture the word STACK, string is finished by char(13). To know where the char(13) is, we get the length in second byte (5), increase it by 1 and use it as offset. There is char(13) and we change it by '$'. Next is your code with a new procedure "finish_strings", that does the job:

```
.model small
.stack 0100h
.data
a db 0ah, 0dh,"ENTER FIRSTNAME: $"
b db 0ah, 0dh,"ENTER SECONDNAME: $" 
c db 20d, ?, 20d DUP("$")
d db 20d, ?, 20d DUP("$")           
crlf db 13,10,'$'
.code
main proc
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
call cls
call input       
call finish_strings   ;<========================================
call output

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
main endp

;clear screen
cls proc
mov ax, 0600h
mov bh, 07h
mov cx, 0000h
mov dx, 184fh
int 10h
ret
cls endp

;INPUT
input proc
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, OFFSET a
int 21h
mov ah, 0ah
mov dx, OFFSET c
int 21h
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, OFFSET b
int 21h
mov ah, 0ah
mov dx, OFFSET d
int 21h        
ret
input endp         


;FINISH STRINGS.
finish_strings proc   ;<========================================

;FINISH STRING C.

mov  si, offset c+1
mov  al, [ si ]
mov  ah, 0
add  si, ax
inc  si
mov  al, '$'
mov  [ si ], al

;FINISH STRING D.

mov  si, offset d+1       ;STRING LENGTH.
mov  al, [ si ]           ;AL = STRING LENGTH.
mov  ah, 0                ;CLEAR AH TO USE AX.
add  si, ax               ;USE LENGTH AS OFFSET.
inc  si                   ;LENGTH + 1.
mov  al, '$'
mov  [ si ], al           ;CHANGE 13 BY '$'.

ret    
finish_strings endp


;OUTPUT
output proc

mov  ah, 9
lea  dx, crlf
int  21h

mov ah, 09h
mov dx, OFFSET c+2
int 21h
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, 003h
int 21h
mov ah, 09h
mov dx, OFFSET d+2
int 21h
ret
output endp

end main
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `ret` instruction at the the end of each `proc`, for example

```
;clear screen
cls proc
mov ax, 0600h
mov bh, 07h
mov cx, 0000h
mov dx, 184fh
int 10h
ret             ;<----- insert
cls endp
```

Comment: Thanks it gets rid of some error. But now the output is[  ♥Me ] the firstname is missing..

Comment: You added the `ret` to all three `proc`s?

Comment: yes in cls, input, and in the output. i add them before their endp(s)